# Why angular js did not used last assigned value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="">
        <p>There {{count = 1; (count == 1 ? "is" : "are")}} one of them</p>
        <div ng-init="count = 7; unit = 'days'; collection = 'week'">
            <p>
                There are {{count}} {{unit}} in a {{collection}}.
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here the `count` is first assigned `1` then again assigned `7` but the result show is like this

> There is one of them
>
> There are 1 days in a week.

Why this is happening. Why global scope rule not followed? Last assigned value have to shown!

Comment: Because expression inside `{{}}` (interpolation) are evaluate on each digest cycle. And `count = 1` expression got evaluate several times & you see `7` values,

**Bottom line is don't use `{{}}` to do assignment to variables**

Comment: It was assigned but overwritten to one again when template is rendered in the next digest cycle.

Comment: @PankajParkar you should write your comment as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because expression inside `{{}}` (interpolation) are evaluate on each digest cycle to keep binding in sync with whatever you have in respective `models`.
And `count = 1` expression got evaluate several times whenever digest cycle gets kicks off, thus you see 7 values.

> **Bottom line is don't use {{}} to do assignment to variables. Always to declaration of variable inside controller. `ng-init` is also not got Idea and best to initialize variable do it inside controller itself.**

Comment: thanks for the clear reply. Could you please point any online reference.

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan you can refer [this article](https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/) & [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/).

Answer (score 0):

If you not investigating this particular case with values assignment in Angular, but building some component to show correct message based on value, keep in mind [`ngPluralize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPluralize) directive.

With that you could refactor your component to this:

```
<ng-pluralize count="count"
              when="{'one': 'There is one {{unit}} in a {{collection}}',
                     'other': 'There are {} {{unit}}s in a {{collection}}'}">
</ng-pluralize>
```

You could play with this plunk: http://www.webpackbin.com/N1uAIycAZ